# Right-align cell content in Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to align text. However, the text is not aligned.

```
Cell lastCell = lastCell = row.createCell(cellNumber++);
if (value != null) {
    lastCell.setCellValue(value);
}
CellStyle cellStyle = lastCell.getCellStyle();
cellStyle.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_RIGHT);
lastCell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
```

Comment: Another challenge is I want cell styles to be different for each cell.

Answer (score 25):

You can replace:

```
cellStyle.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_RIGHT);
```

with:

```
cellStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);
```

Answer (score 9):

```
    lastCell = row.createCell(cellNumber++);

    CellStyle cellStyle = row.getSheet().getWorkbook().createCellStyle();
    cellStyle.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_RIGHT);
    lastCell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

    if (number != null) {
        lastCell.setCellValue(number);
    }
```

Create a new cell style from workbook.

```
    CellStyle cellStyle = row.getSheet().getWorkbook().createCellStyle();
```